# Bluring part of div CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to blur select fixed parts of a div which is filled with images in a cross-browser manner using only CSS (so without SVG, JS, etc.)?

For example, as the 'Trailer' and other apps in iOS7 use blur in the header and navigation tabs.

Comment: Basically...no. Although you could add extra elements and fake it.

Comment: blurring should be considered as some kind of advanced visual feature, so you can just support it for webkit-based browsers on which you can use pure CSS to have a blur effect.

Comment: @KingKing Well, I think I can somehow manage using opacity for non-webkit and using blur for webkit. But, how would I go about applying it to only a part of div?

Comment: @user3525134 I think you may have to use some nested layers to achieve what you want although it's not really good but it's the only approach for a pure CSS solution, try a [demo here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/D2STC/4/)